# nginx location regex that ensures a trailing slash

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I want to ensure that my nginx location directive requires a trailing slash at the end, for some reason it doesn't work for me:

```
location ~* (^[\w]*/$)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What about `location ~* ^(.*/)$`? Or ``location ~* /$``?

Comment: All Nginx URIs have a leading `/` so `\w*` will not match, you need to use `/\w*` instead.